# What does “it” refer to in this song by Kensington?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

To what does ‘it’ refer in ["Part of Me" by Kensington](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZHJoaSuVMs)? What is "a part of me"?

> It is a part of me
> And it breaks my heart to see
> I was a part of you
> When no one else could be